# Why ConLL is not in XML format

Tags: nlp, data-formats

I am new to NLP, I found a format named ConLL which seems a tab-separated file,
like

```
ID FORM LEMMA PLEMMA POS PPOS FEAT PFEAT HEAD PHEAD DEPREL PDEPREL
```

I found a dependency Treebank in this format for Persian. I would like to do some experiment on it. I am familiar with C# and C# has great libraries for XML document files.

I just wonder why such a corpus is not in XML format! I don't say a sophisticated one but they could put each line in a node of XML. Then at least, I would know what is the tag for each element.

However, I can convert it to XML.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for sure is, that you can easialy open it in spreadsheet viewer.

Answer (score 1):

ConLL is a format optimised for processing efficiency (both speed and memory usage).

XML formats for NLP often have the annotation layers one after the other; therefore you have to hold the whole file in memory for processing it.

A drawback of ConLL is that you have to put in fillers (e.g., `0`) for sparse annotations.